# How to sort a single column of data by VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

Can you explain why this attempt to sort a column of data fails?

```
DataColumn.AutoFit
DataColumn.Select
Range(DataColumn.Address).Sort Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlN
```

Error:

> Method sort of Class Range failed.

Edit #1: According to microsoft, Key1 is Optional.
Fixed typo `Range(DataColumn.Address).Sort Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo` but the error is still the same.
Edit #2: Warcupine was right. I added the Key1 and it passed now. Thank you. `Range(DataColumn.Address).Sort Order1:=xlAscending, Key1:=Range(DataColumn.Offset(-1).Address), Header:=xlNo` working code.

Comment: Please fix the presumable typo `xlN` in your question.

Comment: You need to put in a `Key1` parameter

Comment: Microsoft docs are less than stellar, you need Key1. Even if you didn't need it order1 is based off of key1.

Comment: `Range(DataColumn.Address)` is actually `DataColumn` hence `DataColumn.Sort Key1:=DataColumn, Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes`, `DataColumn.Select` being redundant.

Comment: `Range(DataColumn.Address)` in addition to being a little redundant, will not give you the  outcome you expect if the sheet on which `DataColumn` is located is not the active sheet when your code runs: it would instead give you the same range but on the active sheet.